# Loading audio message takes too long

Tags: swift, firebase, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using JSQMessageViewController for my real-time chatting app UI, and firebase for my chatting app database. For text message and image message, the loading still consider OK, but when it comes to audio message, it take very long time. Here is my code for retrieving audio message:

```
func observeMessages() {

    let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(Id).child(senderId).queryLimited(toLast: 50)
    userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let messageId = snapshot.key
        let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)

        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if (dictionary["fromId"] as? String ?? "" == self.userId ? dictionary["toId"] as? String ?? "" : dictionary["fromId"] as? String ?? "") == self.contactLists.first?.id{

                let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: dictionary["timestamp"] as? Double ?? 0.0)

                let textString = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
                let imgString = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
                let voiceString = dictionary["voiceUrl"] as? String ?? ""

                if textString == "image"{

                    let imageView = AsyncPhotoMediaItem(withURL: URL(string: imgString)!)
                    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: dictionary["toId"] as? String ?? "", senderDisplayName: "", date: date as Date, media: imageView)
                    self.messages.append(message!)

                }else if textString == "voice"{

                    print("voice msg")
                    let url = URL(string: voiceString)
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                    let voiceData = data
                    let voice1 = JSQAudioMediaItem(data: voiceData)

                    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: dictionary["toId"] as? String ?? "", senderDisplayName: "", date: date as Date, media: voice1)
                    self.messages.append(message!)

                }else{

                    print("text msg")
                    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: dictionary["toId"] as? String ?? "", senderDisplayName: "", date: date as Date, text:  dictionary["text"] as? String ?? "")
                    self.messages.append(message!)

                }

            }; DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

            }

            self.finishReceivingMessage(animated: true)

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Is there any other way to do it or enhance it?

Comment: Why do you add a query and iterate over the messages using .childAdded then then go back and reload the same message from the ones just loaded? In other words, if you know the message you want to load, why have a query? Just load the message.

Comment: Also, you don't need *DispatchQueue.main.async* as UI functions run on the main thread inside Firebase closures.

Comment: So the reason this audio is loading slowly is because the entire message is loaded before it can be played. In other words you aren't "streaming" the audio. Depending on your file size / internet speed this will cause a delay of several seconds. Apps like Spotify avoid this by using [HLS](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/). However, this involves transcoding the audio and storage for this is not supported by Firebase.Your best bet would be not to show the user they have an audio message until after it's completely loaded. This avoids the user noticing the delay.

Comment: so what should I do now? save the audio in local database? or use any lib to enhance it? @DoesData